# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

While I am trying to overwrite Hive managed table to external table I am getting below error.

```
Query ID = hdfs_20150701054444_576849f9-6b25-4627-b79d-f5defc13c519
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1435327542589_0049, Tracking URL = http://ip-XXX.XX.XX.XX ec2.internal:8088/proxy/application_1435327542589_0049/
Kill Command = /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1435327542589_0049
Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2015-07-01 05:44:11,676 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1435327542589_0049 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-0:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: hi jana, Please add the yarn logs for the container "application_1435327542589_0049". This show the detailed description abt the exception.

Comment: hi karthic, thanks for ur reply while checking yarn file below path /var/log/hadoop/yarn . There is no log file available .Please do the need full

Comment: okay fine. can you please find out the logs in userlogs!! present in 8088 webui of yarn.?

Comment: unable to findour log files. Can you please guide me where i need to check the log files.

Comment: Did you statred the job history server if means go to yarn web ui by this address http://localhost:8088 in that go to tools -> locallogs -> userlogs and find oout the logs by the container id or job id

Comment: in my case its just showing :Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster